# Why must a Hebrew slave who has to work six years only be released after the seventh year?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, law, deuteronomy, jeremiah

In Jeremiah 34:14, we read that a Hebrew slave which has served six years must be let go at the end of the seventh year:

> [Jer 34:14](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/jer/34/14/t_conc_779014):
> מִקֵּץ שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים תְּֽשַׁלְּחוּ אִישׁ אֶת־אָחִיו הָעִבְרִי אֲשֶֽׁר־יִמָּכֵר לְךָ וַעֲבָֽדְךָ שֵׁשׁ שָׁנִים וְשִׁלַּחְתֹּו חָפְשִׁי מֵֽעִמָּךְ
> <sub>'At the end of seven years each of you must set free the fellow Hebrew who has been sold to you and has served you six years; you must set him free from your service.' (ESV)</sub>

It is odd that someone who has worked *six* years must be let go after the *end* (קץ) of the *seventh* year. This is a reference to a rule from Exodus 21:2 and Deuteronomy 15:12, both of which are clear about the time: the slave serves six years and must be let go in the seventh year.

> [Exod 21:2](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/exo/21/2/t_conc_71002):
> כִּי תִקְנֶה עֶבֶד עִבְרִי שֵׁשׁ שָׁנִים יַעֲבֹד וּבַשְּׁבִעִת יֵצֵא לַֽחָפְשִׁי חִנָּֽם
> <sub>When you buy a Hebrew slave, he shall serve six years, and in the seventh he shall go out free, for nothing. (ESV)</sub>
>
> [Deut 15:12](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/deu/15/12/t_conc_168012):
> כִּֽי־יִמָּכֵר לְךָ אָחִיךָ הָֽעִבְרִי אֹו הָֽעִבְרִיָּה וַעֲבָֽדְךָ שֵׁשׁ שָׁנִים וּבַשָּׁנָה הַשְּׁבִיעִת תְּשַׁלְּחֶנּוּ חָפְשִׁי מֵעִמָּֽךְ
> <sub>If your brother, a Hebrew man or a Hebrew woman, is sold to you, he shall serve you six years, and in the seventh year you shall let him go free from you. (ESV)</sub>

Gesenius 18th ed. lists Jer 34:14 under temporal meanings of קץ, i.e. "Ablauf", that is "ending". The only way I see to reconcile Jer 34:14 with that meaning is to understand the law as: "you may let the Hebrew slave work for six years for you and then let him go after at most one year — i.e., before the end of the seventh year he must have gone free." But such an understanding would be odd, why would the owner get the right to keep the slave for a whole year after his time of service?

Are there other possible readings for קץ, or is there cultural-historical data that makes the above suggested rule seem less odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deuteronomy 15:1 also uses the words מִקֵּץ שֶֽׁבַע שָׁנִים "at the end of seven years." The next verses (15:9) discuss someone who doesn't want to give a loan because "the seventh year is *approaching*." A simple reading of these verses seems to be saying that what is discussed happens at the beginning of the seventh year, similar to the seventh year of Exodus 23:11.

While this verse is usually interpreted (at least in Jewish contexts) to mean that the relinquishing of debts happens at the *end* of seven years, I have seen pointed out that the Mishna (Shevi'it 10:8-9) also seems to assume a relinquishing of debts at the beginning of the year.

Ibn Ezra on the verse in Deuteronomy also shares this understanding, and brings Deuteronomy 31:10 as a proof, which refers to "the end of seven years" and specifies the holiday of Sukkot (Tabernacles), which was at the beginning of the year. Interestingly, though, that holiday (if you identify Asif with Sukkot) is in fact described as "the end of the year" in Exodus 23:16.

While the two verses above aren't an absolute proof, if this interpretation is true, "the end of seven years" in Jeremiah doesn't necessarily mean the end of the year, but could refer to the beginning of the seventh year, which is consistent with the laws regarding a Hebrew slave in Exodus and Deuteronomy.

Comment: +1 Another factor can be the potential conflict over an individual slave working six years before their release and the national requirement, which would apply to all slaves. IOW at the start of the 7th year some slaves may not have worked six years. Nevertheless, at the end of the seventh year they must be released.

Comment: Oh I see. "End" like how Sunday is a weekend day even though it's at the beginning.

Comment: @Austin Not exactly. "End" like how Saturday morning is the end of the week even though it's the beginning of the last day

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the Hebrew slave does not choose to work 6 years.  Slaves were generally in place to pay a debt or to provide for the slaves family if they could not provide for themselves.  You could set time limits on how long you would be willing to be a slave.  However, the above referenced rules seem to indicate that, for example, if your fellow Israelite owed you 10 years of service, you were not allowed to keep him beyond the  7th year.  All Hebrew slaves had to be released regardless of what was left on your agreement/sentence if that makes sense.  It was to safeguard the poor.  It is also interesting that many of these old Testament slaves might choose to remain a slave for life by boring their ear to the same doorpost of the Passover.  Generally this was done in order for them to keep a bride that they obtained from their master during their slavery.

Comment: I understand the reason for the rule, but it is unclear why someone who has to work for *six* years must be released *after* the *seventh* year. What does the slave do in the seventh year?

Comment: Correct, the seventh year, if following God's law, was a year of rest, where no work was done.  That literally would mean a year of living under the provision of the master, without any of the duties of a slave.  It was a benefit to the slave because being freshly freed, He/she could do no work to provide themselves in the 7th year.

Comment: interesting idea - do you have any references, biblical or scholarly, that back that up?

Comment: Lev 25:4 references the year of rest as does Exodus 23:11.  Logic dictates that you would not hire a 6 year slave and provide for him for 7 years for 5 years of work.  Of course, this may have happened from time to time, but I doubt this was a norm.

Comment: Yes, but that does not explain why you should still feed the slave the entire seventh year instead of firing him at the end of the sixth.

Comment: There were all sorts of provisions protecting the poor and protecting slaves.  This essentially is the equivalent of a period of "unemployment" in the US today where you get paid while you are getting back on your feet.

Exodus 21:20 – If you beat your slave literally to death, you will be punished. To say you will be punished means you will be held accountable to the law regarding killing (which is punishable by death). If they somehow pull through, you won’t receive this punishment.
Exodus 21:26 – If you injure your slaves eye or tooth, you must release them and give them their freedom.

Comment: Exodus 23:12 – Your slave gets to rest once a week just as you do. 
Proverbs 30:10 – Don’t tell lies to get slaves in trouble with their masters or you will be the one who is guilty. 
Leviticus 19:20 – You can’t have sexual relations with another person’s slave woman
Deut 23:15 – If a slave escapes a cruel master and comes to you for refuge, you are NOT to return him/her to their master. 
Levitiucs 25:10 – every year of Jubilee (every 50 years), liberty was proclaimed throughout all the land. Every slave and servant would be released and all debts forgiven.

Comment: The other way to become a slave was to pay off a debt. A better term would be indentured servant. If you had borrowed a large sum of money and were unable to pay it back, you could become a slave for a set number of years as payment. 
Leviticus 25:35-43 - You were not to enslave other countrymen, but they could become an indentured servant. You were not to mistreat him or her.
If you enjoyed your life as a slave (because there were laws regarding the fair treatment of slaves), you could choose to stay with your master and have them provide for you and your family. (Deut 15:16-17) .

Comment: There was also a set year where all slaves had to be released (if they chose) regardless how big the debt was or the reason for enslavement

Sorry had to post on multiple comments.

Comment: Thanks. Note that you can also [edit] your post if you want to add information. Thanks for the references. I can see how such a rule fits in the greater picture, but this still seems like a huge benefit for the slave to me, and I don't see how it would have worked in practice (e.g., what would the slave do in that seventh year?). So I accepted the other answer, but thank you for your ideas!

Comment: >Leviticus 25:35-43 - You were not to enslave other countrymen< It would seem necessary to distinguish this from Exd. 21:2/Deut. 15:12 according to the individual's impoverishment.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion reminds me of the Jewish conception of time, how even part of a day is considered a day, so maybe here even part of the 7th year is representative of that year. I.e., Jesus was in the tomb parts of three days, not 72 hours as many of us would count days.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/45869)